# Getting Error in SSRS report rendering in C# window application: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008

I have 1 SSRS Report that deployed on server. I am able to access and see the report in ReportViewer in Test Application(C# Window Application).
But I am not able to access/run the same report in my actual actual application with same piece of code., getting error on the line where I am setting parameters to reportviewer.

Here is the code block that i am using in both Test and Actual Application:

ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[3];

```
            rptViewer.Reset();
            rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/LIVE Reports/LicenceReport";
            rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(@"http://X3dRF45CC/Reportserver", System.UriKind.Absolute);

            parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("IN_TIME_PERIOD_FLAG", txtType.Text, false);
            parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("IN_PLAN_VERSION_ID", txtPlanVersion.Text, false);
            parameters[2] = new ReportParameter("IN_MEDIA_OUTLET_ID", txtNetwork.Text, false);

            // Getting error at this below line in Actual App (but not in Test App)
            rptViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);

            rptViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Please someone help, I am wondering from last 2 days.

Comment: Both Test and Actual Application code are in same .net version and also running on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

If your report server is running under windows authentication. Then it is possible that when you run the report using test application (which is running with user context having correct permissions) it runs fine. But when you run this in the actual application(which is not running in context of user with appropriate permissions) fails with 401 (UnAuthorized) error

Comment: How do we know Report Server is running under window authentication? and how do we set report permission in C# code?

Comment: Report server is just another web application. you need to check iis settings to tell if any web application(in this case your report server) is running under windows authentication. You cant set that permission in c# code. any windows desktop application by default runs under the context of user which has logged on to windows. try running your test application on the same machine as actual application. with the same user logged on to windows.

Comment: I tried the same but no luck.. :( Even I added the test project in actual application and make it as startup project and able to run that report, but not in actual project.

Comment: Try running the "Actual application" on the same machine as the "Test application". It has to be a problem around that area. have you checked the authentication mode on your report server ?